# How to do page redirect in HTML Application (.hta)?

Tags: html

I have tried to put

```
<a href="page2.hta">Go Page 2</a>
```

inside a .hta file. However, it opens a browser when I click on the link.

Is it possible to make it open page2.hta within the same window?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to make the HTA "navigable".

```
<hta:application navigable="yes" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="page2.hta" target="_self">Go Page 2</a>
```

_self renders the link in the current frame (useful for overriding a BASE TARGET)

Comment: I run the .hta as a windows application

Answer (score 1):

If you're implementing a Wizard (or whatever), use the HTA Application as a wrapper around an IFRAME.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496(VS.85).aspx

When you want to flip between "pages", navigate that subframe rather than trying to navigate the .HTA itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a target="_self" in the a href, or a <base target="_self"> in the header of the hta.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mime-type for .hta files on the web server.

Comment: I need to run the hta as a desktop application instead of web